# hist() error: 'breaks' do not span range of 'data' and barplot(, log = "y") error: 'height + offset <= 0

Tags: r, plot, histogram, bar-chart

In the x axis, I have a large amount of data (0:700) 
When I use this :

```
dh <- hist(data)
barplot(dh$counts, log="y", col="white", names.arg=dh$breaks[-1])
```

I get this graphic:

[image]

But I want to get smaller values of breaks.
I tried to modify the breaks value but I get an error

> Error in hist.default(data, breaks = seq(5, 700, by = 10)) : some 'data' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'data'

---

**follow up:**

After setting `breaks = seq(0, 700, by = 10)` as the answer suggests, `hist()` works fine but `barplot()` gives me error:

> error log axis: at least one value 'height + offset <= 0

What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**original issue with `hist`:**

I think you should set breaks `breaks = seq(0, 700, by = 10)`, as you said in your comment, that `range(data)` reports `c(0, 690)`.

`hist.default()` will report error, if the breaks does not cover the range of your data. Your current setting: `breaks = seq(5, 700, by = 10)` has minimum 5 and maximum 695, which is slightly insufficient at the left boundary.

I can easily reproduce the error you saw:

```
set.seed(0); x<-rexp(1000,1)
range(x)
# [1] 0.001700975 6.584532959
hist(x, breaks = seq(0.002, 7.002, by = 0.5))
```

> Error in hist.default(x, breaks = seq(0.002, 7.002, by = 0.5)) : 
>     some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'

**follow-up issue with `barplot`:**

> error log axis: at least one value 'height + offset <= 0

I can guess what happened. Check `min(dh$counts)`, and I think it is 0. You know, `log(0) = -INF`, and you can't plot it.

> Yes I have the 0 value. but why it works before I use seq(0, 700, by = 10)?

Why not have a check on `foo <- hist(data, plot = FALSE)`, and see what bin cells and breaks it chooses? Chances are that `hist()` has wisely chosen bin size, so that no 0 count occurs.

When you try to refine the auto-chosen bin size, you should aim to achieve the same, not incurring 0. (Well, if you don't set `log = "y"` in `barplot()` then it really does not matter.)

I could also give you a trick/cheat. You might do `barplot(dh$counts + 1, log = "y", ...)`. After adding 1, the minimum `log` value is 0, and there is no problem at all! Surely the counts values changes, but most likely it is not noticeable on your plot for presentation.